# Compare the first string ending with ; in 2 txt files and get only those lines that are unique

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk

I'm trying to compare 2 txt files and get only those lines that are unique, the problem is that lines want to compare only on the basis of 1 word that ends with a sign; because it's just what interests me

This is the example line:

```
000000423B;Name;26.46;32.55;0;06;pc.
```

I need to find out if the text file is also `000000423B` and if it does not display it or save it to a file

```
awk 'NR == FNR {exclude [$ 0]; next}! ($ 0 in exclude)' 1.txt 2.txt
and
grep -xvFf 1.txt 2.txt> 3.txt
```

They give nice results but they compare the whole line and I need to compare only to the first character;

Any idea?

My input

```
1.txt:
000000423B;Name;27.47;33.79;0;06;szt.
000010001;Name2;4.42;5.44;0;08;szt.
000010001D;Name3;1.68;2.06;0;06;szt.
```

```
2.txt
000000423B;Name;97.47;33.79;0;06;szt.
000010001;Name2;4.99;5.44;0;08;szt.
000010001D;Name3:8778;1.68;2.06;0;06;szt.
009999999;Name4:99999;1.68;2.06;0;96;szt.
```

I want get result:

```
009999999;Name4:99999;1.68;2.06;0;96;szt.
```

In 1.txt and 2.txt first three lines have that same "product id" but other price and I do not care. I need to find only new "product id", these are the first digits to the character " ; "

Comment: Can you explain more and add a minimal example (input, expected output)? First you said `only on the basis of 1 word that ends with a sign` (btw, what sign exactly?) but then you said `compare only to the first character`.

Comment: 1.txt:
000000423B;Name;27.47;33.79;0;06;szt.
000010001;Name2;4.42;5.44;0;08;szt.
000010001D;Name3;1.68;2.06;0;06;szt.

2.txt
000000423B;Name;97.47;33.79;0;06;szt.
000010001;Name2;4.99;5.44;0;08;szt.
000010001D;Name3:8778;1.68;2.06;0;06;szt.
009999999;Name4:99999;1.68;2.06;0;96;szt.

Result:
009999999;Name4:99999;1.68;2.06;0;96;szt.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: I edit question and add more information.

Comment: How do you decide you want `009999999;Name4:99999;1.68;2.06;0;96;szt.` instead of `000000423B;Name;27.47;33.79;0;06;szt.` according to your question, you wanted to compare only on the basis of 1 word that ends with a sign; (what sign `+/-` sign?, there are none). It seems the output you want does not have a basis in the question for determining it. (unless you want to take the first line from `2.txt` that matches criteria from `1.txt`. `uniq < <(sort 1.txt) < <(sort 2.txt) | head -n 1` gives your wanted answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your command and make it work only for the first column, you can do this :

```
awk -F';' 'NR == FNR {exclude [$1]; next} !($1 in exclude)' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Comment: Work perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
join -t';' -11 -21 -v1 -v2 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
```

- sort both files. Note I didn't need to specify `-t';' -k1.1`, because we are joining on the first field from file.
- join the sorted files

  - `-t';'` using `;` as a separator
  - `-11 -21` on first field from both files
  - `-v1 -v2` print unmatched lines from first and second file. Actually `-v2` would be enough, dunno if your interested in unmatching lines from first file too. If not, remove `-v1`.